# javascript how to use sort funtion on an objects property that is in an array

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript program that uses an array of objects. The object has 3 properties. One of them is grade. I am trying to access that object's property and use the sort function to get the max and min score that user has input. Having trouble understanding how to accesses this field and use the .sort function on it. this is what i have:

```
var studentArr = [];

  function Student(name, grade, id) {
  this.name = name;
  this.grade = grade;
  this.id = id; 
}

function summ() {

        var namip = document.getElementById("inp").value;
        var gradip = document.getElementById("inps").value;
        var idip = document.getElementById("inpsid").value;

        var nwStudent = new Student(namip, gradip, idip);
        var grade;
        var average;
        var totalc;
        var sum = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < studentArr.length; i++) {
                sum += parseInt(studentArr[i].grade);
            }
            average = sum / nwStudent.grade.length;
            document.getElementById("aop").innerHTML ="Average score: <br>" + average;

        if (gradip.valueOf() == 70) {

                grade = "C";
                document.getElementById("opo").innerHTML = grade;
        }

        if (gradip.valueOf() == 80) {

                grade = "B";
                document.getElementById("opo").innerHTML = grade;
        }

        if (gradip.valueOf() == 90) {

                grade = "A";
                document.getElementById("opo").innerHTML = grade;
        }

        for(i=0; grade == "C"; i++)
        {
            totalc = totalc + i;
        }

    //  document.getElementById("cop").innerHTML = totalc; 

        studentArr.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
        document.getElementById("hop").innerHTML = "Max Score is: <br>" + studentArr[0];

        studentArr.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
        document.getElementById("lop").innerHTML = "Min Score is: <br>" + studentArr[grade];

    }

</script>
```

Comment: What's the issue? If `a` and `b` are the objects then return `b.grade - a.grade`. You don't show what's actually in the array so no clue how to provide any specific advice, but right now you're not doing anything with the grade in your `sort` function at all.

Comment: Sorting isn't a particularly efficient way to get this information, either.

Answer (score 0):

The sorting function gets two student objects passed in, so you would need to return the comparison of their .grade properties.

```
studentArr.sort(function(a, b){return b.grade-a.grade});
```

Comment: Kevin, thank you. I understand, was not aware I could do that. Now when I input my values and click on button I get [object Object] for my max and mix output values. I do not understand if this means they need to be converted to string, if so how or where would I apply this?

Comment: i think you just need to sort once by grade and then use studentArr[0].grade for the min and studentArr[studentArr.length-1].grade for the max